# The reply address does not match the reply addresses configured for the application

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**SOLVED**: For other people having this error, please check this:

I configured my endpoint/reply address as http:// whilst my app was running https://.. After changing it to `https` things worked as expected and I could login on the v2 endpoint as well as query the graph api.

It's also a **restriction** on the v2 endpoint, so beware of that. It just **needs to be in https**, see the docs:

> Restrictions on redirect URIs
>   Currently, apps that are registered in the Application Registration Portal are restricted to a limited set of redirect URI values. The redirect URI for web apps and services must begin with the scheme `https`.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations

---

I have configured an application via the `apps.dev.microsoft.com` portal as described in [this sample project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample).

I was running under a different port though, so when I set up the URLs in the app registrations I changed them to match my port number.

Now I'm receiving this error after the flow is trying to connect back to my application.

How can I debug this, or how do I know what is happening?

**Additional technical information**:

```
Correlation ID: 145d8f37-7229-4dce-8ace-c777e4aeef94
Timestamp: 2017-11-02 08:41:21Z
AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://localhost:60761/signin-oidc' 
             does not match the reply addresses configured for the
             application: '8b640f9d-e7d8-4c41-8a40-15069f5712ee'. 
             More details: not specified
```

[image]

I also get the notification that this application will be fed to the Azure AD Portal (app registrations) - but I can't find it there.

Comment: Can you profile a screen shot of the redirect uris you have configured in `apps.dev.microsoft.com`?

Comment: thanks Marc, 't was because I didn't define an https:// endpoint..

Comment: Suggestion: Remove the upper section from this question and instead use it to create a proper answer, Q&A style. :)